# ChartJS tooltip to always show on graph (for mode "label/index")

Tags: javascript, c#, chart.js, tooltip

I have a stacked bar chart and I want to always display the tooltip on my stacked bar. I manage to get it to work but the result is not what I want. It displayed the tooltip for each stacked bar separately; what I want is to show the tooltip for both the stacked bar in one / grouped.

By using tooltip option mode: 'label' or 'index', it works but only work on hover (mouse over). I want to display the grouped tooltip always on the graph.

Below the code that I am currently using:

In plugin service register, below was added to always show the tooltip on the graph:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
            beforeRender: function(chart) {
                //chart.options.tooltips.mode = 'index';

                var datasets = chart.data.datasets;
                chart.pluginTooltips = [];
                for (i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < datasets[i].data.length; j++) {
                        if (Number(datasets[i].data[j]) > 0) {
                            chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                                _chart: chart.chart,
                                _chartInstance: chart,
                                _data: chart.data,
                                _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                                _active: [chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data[j]]
                            }, chart));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }, // end beforeRender

            afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart, easing) {

                // Draw tooltips
                Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
                    tooltip.initialize();
                    tooltip.update();
                    tooltip.pivot();
                    tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
                });
            } // end afterDatasetsDraw

        });
```

In the chart option, below tooltip option was added:
*tooltip with label mode was to show the tooltip as a group; this only works on hover, I want to get it to work to always display on the graph.

```
tooltips: {
                    mode: 'label',
```

Below the result that I currently get:

[image: current]

Below the expected result that I want to have (it only shows on hover now):

[image: expected]

My question is: How can I draw the grouped tooltip (as shown above) to display always (fixed) on the graph.